# Using T-SQL find the Stored Procedure associated to an SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I had some help writing this query -- I'm at a bit of a loss because i'm trying to find the the query type or procedure used and i'm not sure what else to add to the query or how to change it.

```
SELECT      
    Ds.Name as Data_Source_Name,
    C2.Name AS Data_Source_Reference_Name,
    C.Name AS Dependent_Item_Name,
    C.Path AS Dependent_Item_Path,
    ds.*
FROM
    ReportServer.dbo.DataSource AS DS
INNER JOIN  
    ReportServer.dbo.Catalog AS C ON DS.ItemID = C.ItemID 
                                  AND DS.Link IN (SELECT ItemID 
                                                  FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
                                                  WHERE Type = 5) --Type 5 identifies data sources
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C2 ON DS.Link = C2.ItemID
WHERE
    C2.Type = 5
    AND c.name LIKE '%mkt%'
ORDER BY    
    C.Path, C2.Name ASC, C.Name ASC;
```

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe you will find it in any of the tables directly.   That's part of the rdl report file and that is stored in the Content column in the Catalog table.  It's stored there as BLOD.  You need to convert it, something like "convert (varchar(max), convert (varbinary(max),[Content]))" and then basically parse the xml to find it.

Comment: Can you download the rdl from report services or sharepoint? and if so, open it with Visual Studios and you can easily look up the name of proc (even if your data source is not pointing to right server). Finding the right server you just click where ever your downloaded the file from i.e. report server or sharepoint and navigate to data source folder and can find your data source associated with this specific rdl. If your doing it manually. Automated answers are below dbo.Catalog is your pal if yo want to baby step hunt this sp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my comment, give this a try, should get you moving in the right direction on how you can parse the xml and zero in on the specific command.

You might have to update the name spaces in the script below and also add your report name.

But try something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition') --You may have to change this based on you SSRS version
SELECT
    [Path],
    Name,
    report_xml.value( '(/Report/DataSources/DataSource/@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) AS DataSource,
    report_xml.value( '(/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query/CommandText/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) AS CommandText, 
    report_xml.value( '(/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query/CommandType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS CommandType, 
    report_xml
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        [Path], 
        Name, 
        [Type],
        CAST( CAST( content AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS XML ) report_xml 
    FROM dbo.[Catalog]
    WHERE Content IS NOT NULL
    AND [Type] = 2
    ) x
WHERE 
--use below in where clause if searching for the CommandText.  Depending on how the report was developed I would just use the proc name and no brackets or schema.
--Example:  if you report was developed as having [dbo].[procName] just use LIKE '%procName%' below.  Because other reports could just have dbo.procName.
report_xml.value( '(/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query/CommandText/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) LIKE '%Your Proc Name here%'
--comment out the above and uncomment below if know your report name and want to search for that specific report.
--[x].[Name] = 'The Name Of Your Report'
```

Comment: Hello, Am I looking for CommandText Field? I added my procedure name to the single quotes you have outlined -- the result set was empty? I know there exists a report (as i built it) with my procedure (my big issue is where else its used). But It's not coming back, nothing is coming back? Does this query return every single .rdl file?

Comment: @Elizabeth No, originally that is not how I had the example, where you could search for all reports that have certain text in the CommandText field.  I was just giving an example on how to look at one specific report based on name.   I updated my answer and added comments on how you can do that.

Comment: I'm getting NULL values in the CommandText column for some reports. When I open the report XML it has a value within the <CommandText> tag for those reports, though it's not getting displayed in the output obtained from the above code.

Answer (score 3):

You're in the right neighborhood... When a report RDL is published its XML is converted into a image data type and stored in dbo.Catalog.Content.

If you convert the image data to VARBINARY(MAX) and then convert to XML, you'll be able to read the XML in plain text.

```
SELECT TOP (10)
    *
FROM
    dbo.Catalog c
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), c.Content))) ) cx (content_xml)
WHERE 
    c.Type = 2;
```

From there it's just a matter of parsing the XML to dig out what you're looking for. In this case you looking for tags that look like the following...

```
<DataSet Name="My_stored_proc">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is implied here - the query returns a lot of information. I don't know what field i'm supposed to parse out? is it  content_xml?

Comment: Nothing is implied here... In fact I was very specific. You need to 1) convert Catalog.Conten to BINARY, 2) convert the binary to XML and then 3) parse the XML to find the specifc information you're looking for... If you're looking at the script I provided, I took care of 1 & 2 ("cx.content_xml"). If you look at Tim's answer, he is doing the exact same thing... plus parsing the XML for several specific tags.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the stored procedure name? If your looking to see where that is at its in the database itself, database > DatabaseName > Programmability > Stored Procedures. If your trying to use the query you built for a report you need to make the stored procedure or change the query type to text and paste it in the box.

Comment: I am looking for the stored procedure names for all the reports on the server. and yes i'm trying to query the data. (i don't want to change anything just pull the information)